# How to make a <ul> display in a horizontal row

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How can I make my list items appear horizontally in a row using CSS?

```css
#div_top_hypers {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    display:inline;      
}
#ul_top_hypers {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_top_hypers">
    <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Inbox</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Compose</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Reports</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Preferences</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 181, accepted):

List items are normally block elements. Turn them into inline elements via the `display` property.

In the code you gave, you need to use a context selector to make the `display: inline` property apply to the list items, instead of the list itself (applying `display: inline` to the overall list will have no effect):

```css
#ul_top_hypers li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Here is the working example:

```css
#div_top_hypers {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    display:inline;      
}
#ul_top_hypers li{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_top_hypers">
    <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Inbox</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Compose</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Reports</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Preferences</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also achieved this effect by using float, thereby keeping the block nature of the list items.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I have to say—however, I think that would create some unnecessary hassles with margins and such, since you're effectively lifting the list items out of the box model.

Comment: @htw: You could kick it back into gear with any of the clearfix solutions.

Comment: You could always use display:inline-block if you wanted to retain the block nature... though it's not completely supported at this stage (I believe it's Fx2 that's the major culprit).

Comment: where is flexbox of doing that ? like  >> flex-direction: row;

Answer (score 21):

You could also set them to float to the right.

```css
#ul_top_hypers li {
    float: right;
}
```

This allows them to still be block level, but will appear on the same line.

Comment: Floating them right will have an extra affect: it will swap the order of them so from left to right they will be last to first.

Comment: Ah yes, they'll need to be reversed in the markup (so much for separation of layout/markup!)

Answer (score 17):

As others have mentioned, you can set the `li` to `display:inline;`, or `float` the `li` left or right.  Additionally, you can also use `display:flex;` on the `ul`.  In the snippet below I also added `justify-content:space-around` to give it more spacing.

For more information on flexbox, checkout this [complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#ul_top_hypers {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_top_hypers">
    <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Inbox</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Compose</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Reports</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> Preferences</a></li>
        <li>&#8227; <a href="" class="a_top_hypers"> logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Set the `display` property to `inline` for the list you want this to apply to.  There's a good explanation of displaying lists on [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/).

Answer (score 10):

As @alex said, you *could* float it right, but if you wanted to keep the markup the same, float it to the left!

```css
#ul_top_hypers li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**It will work for you:**

```css
#ul_top_hypers li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#ul_top_hypers li {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align list items(li) horizontally without affecting list style use below mentioned properties.
`ul{ display:flex; gap:30px; }`
gap:30px this used to set the gap between the list items.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific use this:

```
#div_top_hypers ul#ul_top_hypers li{
display: inline;
}
```