# trying to get images to line up horizontally

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get a set of images to line up on screen horizontally.

```css
#full_image {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#full_image ul li img {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="full_image">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're creating a new list with each image, for starters; and each list is a block-level (not inline) element. Block elements start on a new line, by default.

Then, your `display: inline` is applied to the images, not to the `li` that contains them, which is still at block level.

Finally, `list-style: none` doesn't make sense on a `div`. I assume you mean to apply it to a list.

So:

```css
#full_image {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#full_image li {
  display: inline;
}

#full_image li img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<ul id="full_image">
  <li>
    <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that does work but I need the ul li tags because I'm going to use it in a image slider

Comment: How can you then get the whole thing to be centered?

Comment: @SumNeuron There are plenty of ways to do that. Look at the "Related" list on the right side of this page, particularly the first few "how to center..." questions.

Comment: I have looked at these, but these solutions do not work with the inline img tags :/

Comment: Almost certainly doable through CSS. Pull together sample HTML showing the issue, and CSS you've tried, and [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

remove tags ul li and try again

Comment: I need the ul li tags because I'm going to use it in a image slider

Comment: maybe this can help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/make-ul-elements-appear-in-a-horizontal-row

Answer (score 0):

Remove the list tags

http://jsfiddle.net/cxfNb/ they line up fine. If you want the bullet points, you'll have to remove the block style of the ul and li tags

```
<div id="full_image"> 
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>   
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>  
  <a href="#"> <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01636/saint-tropez-beach_1636818c.jpg" alt="" /></a>  
</div>
```