# Align three images in footer side by side

Tags: html

I'm trying to align three hyperlinked icons side by side similar to what is shown on this website at the bottom of my blog http://oxter.in I'm creating a similar Facebook, Instagram etc. kind of link set in the footer of my page. I have the theme Port and am using it's footer - text widget to create the links.

I am able to create the icons as links but they do not align side by side.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a list of references that you want and display them `inline`. you can have look at this question :
[How to make a <ul> display in a horizontal row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/make-ul-elements-appear-in-a-horizontal-row)

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;`, `float: right;`, or `display: inline-block;` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by many ways,

### First Way:

```
float:left/right;
display:inline;
```

### Second Way:

Create UL with LI and apply these properties:

```
float:right;
display:inline;
list-style:none;
```

Second way will help you a lot in future.

Kind regards,
Ishfaque Ahmed