# align li elements on right side

Tags: html, css

I have `li` like below in my code

```
<ul class="thumbnails-carousel clearfix" style="list-style:none;">
  <li><img src="http://s2.postimg.org/h6uti3zud/1_tn.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/n4fjr7q2n/2_tn.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/afuhmf61f/3_tn.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/p45dxi6hf/4_tn.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I want these images to be on the right hand side of each image instead of going below each other.

Comment: `li {float: left;}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float:left` as well as `display:inline-block`

```
ul li{
  float:left;
}
```

OR

```
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul class="thumbnails-carousel flex" style="list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <img src="http://s2.postimg.org/h6uti3zud/1_tn.jpg" alt="1.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://s27.postimg.org/n4fjr7q2n/2_tn.jpg" alt="2.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/afuhmf61f/3_tn.jpg" alt="3.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://s29.postimg.org/p45dxi6hf/4_tn.jpg" alt="4.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add
  `li{float:left;}` to your css code

Answer (score 1):

You can also use display: inline, [per this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/make-ul-elements-appear-in-a-horizontal-row):

```css
li {display: inline;}
```

```html
List items are block elements, and as such, take up an entire line each before breaking. Inline elements are not block elements and as such can then share space on a line.
<ul class="thumbnails-carousel clearfix" style="list-style:none;">
  <li><img src="http://s2.postimg.org/h6uti3zud/1_tn.jpg" alt="1.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/n4fjr7q2n/2_tn.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/afuhmf61f/3_tn.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
 <li><img src="http://s29.postimg.org/p45dxi6hf/4_tn.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```