# HTML center nav bar

Tags: html, css, center, nav

How can I center my nav bar, but still appear as a line in the top of the site? I know i must change something in the css file where li is built, but i can't figure it out. The code is:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the css file is like:

```
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #791519;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a <ul> display in a horizontal row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/how-to-make-a-ul-display-in-a-horizontal-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap it in an NAV tag and set on the NAV tag text-align to center.

```
nav {
  text-align:center;
}
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  margin:0 auto;

}


<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZprLXd)

Comment: Thanks! That was much easier than the 1st response! Thanks!

Comment: you should accept this or the one with flex box, I do prefer this method as flex box can be still unsupported.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer your way too, because flex is way too much. With yours, using padding I can make it as tall and long I want. Many thanks!

Comment: One other thing. How can I add a search tab with a button which has an icon to your way?

Comment: Check the code pen. I did a change.. It may suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks again Erik!

Comment: If you mean the icon I added &#128269; myself. But thanks for bothering! Lastly, how can I make it animated? I mean, when you click on the icon, a space like you made, appears on the right of the search icon and not below.

Comment: you may use some padding and an absolute positioned input box.. maybe

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Flex Box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  list-style-type: none;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #791519;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this (add wrap and text-align: center):

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #791519;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make this by changing the position of ul
Check the following css changes for ul

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position:relative;
  left:100px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #791519;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Now I can change the position with pixels! Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't center the nav bar. It only adds 100 pixel spacing at the left.