# Make list evenly spaced and inline

Tags: html, css

I have a html list and I want to make it inline, centered and evenly spaced. Here is the closest I've gotten to the desired result:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
   text-align: center;
   width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 1 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 2 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 3 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

I just can't get them inline

Here is what i want:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a <ul> display in a horizontal row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/how-to-make-a-ul-display-in-a-horizontal-row)

Comment: is there any reason why you wrap each element in a div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for when you said:

> inline, centered and evenly spaced

Note:  You'll probably need to open this full-screen.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 33%;
}

li a {
   width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 1 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `inline-block` and the following is its implementation also there is space between them

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
   text-align: center;
   width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 1 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 2 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
<li><div><a href="#">Item 3 Lorem Ipsum</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a wrapping div and this is preventing the inline for the li to work properly. If you remove the div (ununsed in your example) it works properly:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div {
   text-align: center;
   width: 30vw;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 1 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general approach not using width try

```
.foo li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.foo li a {
  display: block;
 }

<ul>
<li class = "foo"><a href="#">Item 1 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li class = "foo"><a href="#">Item 2 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li class = "foo"><a href="#">Item 3 Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that padding imply width, use margin-right instead