# Bullets are hidden when display: inline is used

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to display `<li>` items in line. But when I use `display:inline` property in CSS bullets becomes hidden. I tried this from [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/how-to-make-a-ul-display-in-a-horizontal-row)

HTML

```html
<div class="list">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the CSS

```css
.list{
   display: inline;
}
.list-inline li{
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
```

`display: inline` seems to work but **bullets become hidden**. How can I fix this? Check out the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trojan14/j5fnb3zp/25/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `display: flex;` for `list-inline` class.

```css
.list{
   display: inline;
}

.list-inline {
  display: flex;
}
.list-inline li{
    margin: 10px;
    /* display: inline; */
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this styles.

```
.list{
    display: inline;
 }
 .list-inline li{
    margin: 10px;
 }
 .list-inline{
    display: flex;
 }
```

Is this you want
You can make the ul a flex box!
If you want to know more about bullets in css, see this w3schools docs

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Answer (score 2):

I think `inline` negates the bullet, but using `flex` with `flex-direction: row;` on the `ul` declaration will have the effect you are looking for...

```css
ul {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

.list {
}

.list-inline li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer just for fun.

You can use the `float` property to float the list items to the left or right of its parent container [ **but make sure to always use overflow on the parent element or use `clear` property on the next element to clear the side effects of `float`** ]

```css
.list-inline{
   overflow: auto;
}

.list-inline li{
   float: left;
   margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
            <li>Hi</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```