# flexbox to make ul wrap

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Currently, my code looks like this.

HTML

```
  return (
    <Card {...props} className={` ${classes.root} ${rootClassName}`} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
        <div className={classes.box}>
          <ul>
          {props.pizzas?.toppings?.map((topping) => (
            <li key={topping.id} className={classes.list}>{topping.name}</li>
          ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </Card>
  );
```

CSS

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 2, 2),
    height: theme.typography.pxToRem(500),
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer',
    },
  },
  box: {
    height: '300px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  list: {
    flex: '0 0 70px',
  }
}));
```

My list looks like the below picture.
I want the list to wrap if there is space without overlapping each other, and if there is space at the bottom which there is right now to stack together if there are more toppings.

[image: Topping List]

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a <ul> display in a horizontal row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885691/how-to-make-a-ul-display-in-a-horizontal-row)

Comment: please show us the html code

Comment: @RonnieRoyston doing it from the link you provided did some thing similar to what I want but i caused the bullets to disappear. As well my list ends up leaving the container, and I don't know why.

Comment: @c.m. HTML code added

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into a similar problem this is how I solved it.

```
 column1: {
    columns: '1',
    width: '300px',
  },
  column2: {
    columns: '2',
    width: '500px',
  },
  column4: {
    columns: '5',
    width: '800px',
  },
```

I used columns